# Difference between startDate and endDate-Symfony

Tags: symfony, validation

Can someone assist me with this, I have a student table and I want to ensure that the user enters a date range from now to 3 months. I tried this but it didn't give me the results I wanted. Thinking about using datediff but not sure where I would put it. Is there another way like using a custom validation to validate the date.

```
* @Assert\Range
     * ( 
     * min= "today", max="+3 months"
     * )

Error message:
```

> This value should be a valid number.

Comment: There definitely is the way to validate date. What results you got and how they are different from what you want?
Have you tried Range validator?

Comment: The range validator simple validated if the value is between a min and max integer, so this will not work for a datetime  EDIT: my bad,   this SHOULD indeed work, according to https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Range.html

Comment: Yes I have tried range validator and its saying this value should be a valid number.

Comment: Here is an example from the symfony documentation `@Assert\LessThanOrEqual("+15 minutes")`  Here is the [link](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-date-support-for-validator-constraints)

Comment: What version of Symfony are you running? Date range support was added in Symfony 2.6

Comment: 2.5 guess that's the problem then..there's no date range support for Symfony 2.5

Answer (score 0):

```
@Assert\Callback(methods={"validatePayrollPeriod"})


  public function validatePayrollPeriod(ExecutionContextInterface $context) {
    $days = $this->startdate->diff($this->enddate)->days;
    if ($days <= 7 || $days > 14) {
        $context->buildViolation('Not a valid payroll period.')
            ->atPath('enddate') 
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try to make a validation in your setter.
Something like

```
public function setEndDate($endDate)
{
    if(your end date - your start date < 3){
        $this->endDate= $endDate;
    }else{
        Throw whatever exepection you cant
   }

    return $this;
}
```